# MOQ verify for execution doens't work

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to mock my internal virtual method.
When I debug I can see I get to where I expect and my internal virtual method is exceuted but the test fails.
Further more, I verified 'this' context is the proxy and not a regular class instance.

Methods:

```
public void MyMethod() { MyInternalMethod() }
internal virtual void MyInternalMethod() {}
```

Piece of unit test:

```
Because of = () => { myMock.Object.MyMethod() };

It should_run_inner_internal_virtual_MyInternalMethod = () =>
{
              myMock.Verify(x => x.MyInternalMethod(),Times.Once());
};
```

I'll appreciate any help.

Kind regards.

Comment: Are you sure you're testing the right thing here? It seems to me that you're trying to test implementation rather than behavior. If you later decide to inline this behavior instead of having a separate method for it, the test will fail even though the behavior didn't change. What is your internal method supposed to do? Can you somehow mock and test that behavior instead?

Comment: I edited the post to more clear. I want to verify the method executed. The funny thing I did it a few days ago and it worked (for another unit) and I inspected the code but I still can't make it work.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but I'm questioning *why* - and I think you should too =) But if you insist: are the methods and the unit test defined in the same assembly?

Comment: They are in different assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure if your code compiles, but I think since Moq and the class under test are in different assemblies, you may need to tell the assembly of the object under test to make internal visible to the Moq's assembly.  internal only makes a method / property / class visible to that assembly.

Try adding this to your AssemblyInfo.cs file (for the assembly under test)

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]
```

assuming DynamicProxyGenAssembly2 is your Moq's assembly name.
If your test is also in a different assembly, then you need to make the internals visible to that assembly as well.
I just wrote a nunit test for this, and it passes.

```
[Test]
public void ShouldCallMyInternalMethodFromMyMethod()
{
  myMock = new Mock<MyClass>();
  myMock.Object.MyMethod();
  myMock.Verify(mockObj=> mockObj.MyInternalMethod(), Times.Once());
}
```

Comment: Hi, my code compiles and I managed to go through debug as expected. Further more other test for this assemblies works.